# How to capture UI Automation info of a remote application

Tags: c#, c++, serial-port, ui-automation, remote-desktop

I have created an application using C# (with WPF) and ATL COM C++. This captures deatails of controls with which the user interacts on a target application. For example, it will record that the user selected an item from a combo box in a dialog in MS Word.
Low level mouse and keyboard hooks are set in C++. The C++ code collects information and sends the info using SendMessage with WM_COPYDATA to a window in C# application. Then the C# application processes the info in its WndProc function.

Now I need to extend the application so that it works when the target application is running on a remote desktop. It should take care of all the methods that are normally used to run an application on a remote desktop, such as Citrix, Remote Desktop Connection of Chrome and others.

Could you tell me how I should proceed on this? Any sample codes? I am reading on SerialPort class in dot Net. But I am not sure if that would be the best way.

Comment: TCP sockets could be appropriate way for sending the data across machines. RDP can't expose UI automation data itself.

Comment: Should I use SerialPort? Currently, this is how I am sending data from C++ dll to a window of C# exe. There is a structure called TagInfo. It has two members. One is fixed size array of another structure called KeyValuePair and the other member is int count. Here count tells how many elements of the array KeyValuePair are to be read. Each KeyValue pair is also a structue, which has two fixed size WCHAR arrays. One is key and the other is value. So even if I have to send a data of type long, I am converting it into WCHAR array and then sending. How to extend this for remote desktop scenario?

Comment: I have not done TCP socket programming but I will read on it and implement if it serves the purpose. But could you tell me some algorithm or design by which I can proceed in the right direction? And any sample code that shows how to send at least one string from server to client and how the client will know that it has received the complete string?

Comment: TCP network protocol already takes care of data integrity and even sending/receiving order. Just search on StackOverflow for TCP sockets in C++ or C#. One socket must be a server (who's listening), another one (or more) is a client as usual. Not sure SerialPort is appropriate thing (never used it sorry) for your purpose.